# I want to debug every HTTPs to my web server with PhpStorm + Xdebug

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have a LAMP web server running as a web server. I'm debugging its PHP code using Xdebug and PhpStorm.

I use Firefox with Xdebug helper enabled to send HTTP request to the web server, PhpStorm catches that request and starts debugging.

Now, I want PhpStorm to catch and debug any HTTP request to the web server (not only requests from Firefox+Xdebug helper). For example, I want to send HTTP requests via CURL/BURPSUITE for debugging purpose.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi NTH, have you looked at a tool such as Wireshark?

Comment: 1) Use "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm so it listens for incoming debug connections. 2) Use `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` in your php.ini (see Derick's answer) -- this tells Xdebug to attempt to debug every single script. Alternatively you can also put `xdebug_break();` into your actual PHP code. 3) Other than that (if you want to control what connections to debug) you have to ether pass a cookie or GET/POST parameter with your request (see Viney's answer)

Comment: Hi LazyOne, your answer is correct! thank you very much!

Comment: @LazyOne thankyou for xdebug_break();

Answer (score 5):

If you want Xdebug to always (try to) make a connection, simply set [`xdebug.remote_autostart=1`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart) in php.ini. Then regardless of whether the cookie (that the Firefox extension sets) is present, Xdebug will make a connection to your IDE.

Comment: I have set this option, and I tried to send to the server a simple request via cURL, the output shows "301 Moved permanently"

Comment: Xdebug doesn't set these headers. And, that sounds like a normal HTTP redirection - cURL will probably tell you were to if you ask it nicely.

Comment: Hi Derick, now it works well, thank you very much for the good answer!

Answer (score 1):

The xdebug helper browser extension works by setting a cookie in the HTTP request so you could try setting a cookie but there is even simpler way - just append this url param (XDEBUG_SESSION_START) and it would trigger xdebug

```
$url='http://mywebsite.com?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm';

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

It works in curl as well as in browser

Here `phpstorm` is the idekey I have configured in php.ini, so change it as per your settings